# Как сформировать функцию, имея ее текст в качестве строки?

Tags: javascript

Как сформировать функцию, имея ее текст в качестве строки?
Дискас.

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/eval

Comment: `f = new Function('a, b', 'return a + b');`

Comment: Вопрос хороший.

Comment: @humster_spb Спасибо, все работает. Оба варианта равнозначны?

Comment: @Yaant Спасибо, все работает. Оба варианта равнозначны?

Comment: Не совсем равнозначны. [Функции, созданные конструктором Function, не создают замыканий на их контексты создания; они всегда создаются в глобальной области видимости. При их вызове, они получат доступ только к своим локальным переменным и переменным из глобальной области видимости, но не к переменным в той области видимости, в которой вызывался конструктор Function. Это поведение отличается от поведения при использовании функции eval с кодом создания функции.](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function#Description)